# SDK error when publishing the application

Tags: swift

good day guys, someone happened the same thing, I have a problem when publishing a new version of my app in the PlayStore, I don't know if it is correct to update my SDK version:
First I got a warning and it went up normal now after about 2 weeks
I am uploading a new update and it sends me this error.

```
               App Store Connect Operation Error
```

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 13.6 SDK. All
iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 14 SDK or later, included in Xcode 12 or later."

my current version of Xcode is 11.6

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new privacy changes released, you should upload your app with Xcode 12 or later. It is also written on error message.

Xcode 11 doesn't have App Tracking Transparency framework so Apple blocks the app's which are uploaded previous version of Xcode 12.

Comment: Thanks for your time my application is in version 11.6 I have some libraries added in for this version in any case humm I would have to update even the libraries, So there is a way

Comment: Yes you must send version with Xcode 12, there is no way.